# Spring exception handling using HttpServletResponse vs ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I tried 2 different ways of implementing an exception handler for `MethodArgumentNotValidException` :

First one using `ResponseEntity`:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler
{
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        Set<String> errors = new HashSet<>();
        for (FieldError error : e.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors())
        {
            builder.append(error.getField()).append(" has invalid value ").append(error.getRejectedValue()).append("; ");
        }

        errors.add(builder.toString());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) ;
    }
}
```

Second one send response directly using `HttpServletResponse`:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler
{
    
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public void handleException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (FieldError error : e.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors())
        {
            builder.append(error.getField()).append(" has invalid value ").append(error.getRejectedValue()).append("; ");
        }

        response.sendError(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, builder.toString());
    }
}
```

The first one is working as expected(by returning the right body) but the second one returns the spring default message("Validation failed for object ...etc..") in body .

What is the difference between those methods and what explains this discrepancy ?

Comment: What does the javadoc of `sendError` say about how it handles the response body?

Comment: ResponseEntity indicates Spring to serialize and return the response as JSON. HttpServletResponse.sendError will not do the JSON conversion and header update.